# Dialog not restricted to specified height

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery dialog configured as such:

```
var dialogOptions = {
    autoOpen:       false, 
    modal:          false,
    draggable:      false,
    resizable:      false, 
    closeOnEscape:  false,
    minHeight:      450,
    minWidth:       800,
    height:         450,
    width:          800,
    create: function() {
        $(this).css("maxHeight", 450).css('maxWidth',800);        
    }

    buttons:        { "Close": function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }}
};

$("#detailDialog").dialog(dialogOptions);
```

The version of jQuery I'm using is jquery-1.7.2.

I open the dialog in response to an href click like such:

```
function openDetailDialog(url) 
{
    $('#detailDialog').dialog({'my':'center', 'at':'center','of':$(this)});
    $('#detailDialog').dialog('open').load(encodeURI(url)); 
}
```

The div that I’m loading looks like this:

```
<div id="detailDialog" style="width:800px;height:450px;overflow-y:scroll;display:none;"></div>
```

The page I’m loading into the dialog is a simple HTML table which displays a SQL dataset.

Now, the dataset can be of any length, ranging from one record to hundreds of records.  This is all working just dandy.

**EVIL PROBLEM:**  I cannot seem to restrict the jQuery dialog to the same size every time.  The first time it displays properly according to the settings above.  Every time thereafter, it is either too short or too long.  Nothing I try seems to correct this.

Do I need a div around the table that's displaying the record set?  I've tried with no avail.

I see lot’s of stuff on SO regarding maxHeight but this attribute seems to be not respected by the dialog.

I’m about ready to say goodbye to dialogs and revert to 1990’s era window pops.

Comment: Two minor things. One, you're missing a comma between your create function and the buttons option, but that's not a big deal even though the dialog has a close button by default so you really don't even need to set the buttons option. B, you created a `dialogOptions` variable but I don't see if being used anywhere. You may want to try and setup an example of the problem at jsFiddle.net and post the link here.

Comment: I'm sorry; I neglected to paste the dialogOptions call in the code.  Please see above, right after the var dialogOptions is set.

Comment: how bout a demo/jsfiddle?

one more thing
instead usign:
`$(this).css("maxHeight", 450).css('maxWidth',800);`
simply use
`$(this).css({"maxHeight": 450, 'maxWidth' : 800});`

Comment: Dhaval:  That seems to have done the trick!  Wow ... so easy.  Works great now in IE and FF.  Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add following css class in your css file

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-dialog-content 
        { height: 450px !important; }
    </style>
```

and please do let me know if you still face problem